# Send Javascript object to PDO for update

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, pdo

I am new to php & really lost. I am trying to take a javascript object with multiple arrays & send it to my php PDO to update my database. I've collected all of my data from my form into a javascript object. I used json.stringify to convert the object into this format. Console.log(updateString) produces:

```
 [{"id":"20","type":"2","content":"3","name":"2","user":"1"}, 
  {"id":"21","type":"2","content":"4","name":"3","user":"1"}]
```

I am using ajax to send to my php:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'add.php',
    data: {
        updates: updateString
    },
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Then in my php code, I decode the json & am trying to update my database:

```
$db= new PDO ('mysql:dbname=xxxx;host=localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$updates = JSON_decode($_POST["updates"], true);
try { 
    $sql = ("UPDATE tableName SET type=:type, content=:content, name=:name, user=:user WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $updates['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":type", $updates['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":content", $updates['content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $updates['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":user", $updates['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo "The changes could not be made.<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
```

I am not getting any errors thrown so I don't know where to start but my database is not updating. I know I will need a foreach loop in my php but I'm trying to get a single array to go through first before I complicate it more. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add code: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the begining. Data is not being saved into the database?

Comment: So what's your question - write proper code for me?

Comment: My question was can you tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: I tried adding error_reporting(E_ALL); but am still not seeing any errors

Comment: `datatype: 'application/json'` should be `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one little change that you should have to make to get this working:

```
try{
    for($i=0; $i<count($updates); $i++){
        $sql = ("UPDATE tableName SET type=:type, content=:content, name=:name, user=:user WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $updates[$i]['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":type", $updates[$i]['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":content", $updates['content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $updates[$i]['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user", $updates[$i]['user'],    PDO::PARAM_STR);      
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo "The changes could not be made.<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
```

**Reason:**
As a standalone code, if you try and run the following, you'll see how the JSON object is received in PHP:

```
$test = '[{"id":"20","type":"2","content":"3","name":"2","user":"1"},

          {"id":"21","type":"2","content":"4","name":"3","user":"1"}]';


$test_array = json_decode($test, true);

for($i=0; $i<count($test_array); $i++){
  echo "<br> Id = ".$test_array[$i]['id']." | ".$test_array[$i]['content'];
}
```

The output produced will be as follows:

```
Id = 20 | 3
Id = 21 | 4
```

---

The `foreach` version for the same code would be:

```
try{
    $sql = ("UPDATE tableName SET type=:type, content=:content, name=:name, user=:user WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":content", $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":user", $user,    PDO::PARAM_STR);      

    foreach($updates as $update_rec){
        $id      = $update_rec['id'];
        $type    = $update_rec['type'];
        $content = $update_rec['content'];
        $name    = $update_rec['name'];
        $user    = $update_rec['user'];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo "The changes could not be made.<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: A `foreach` loop might be easier to manage than a `for` loop.

Comment: @aynber Thanks. Added the `foreach` version too.

Comment: I think this is probably what I needed but I still can't get it working. In debug mode, I can step all the way through the function to the execute line. It shows all variables are there & I never hit the catch so it is succeeding. However, it's still not reflecting in my database. I'm definitely connected as I post to it in other parts of the app. I checked that my localhost has all privileges as well.

Comment: @heat222 Not everything has to essentially fall into `catch`. Please could you add something like `echo "<br>Error code: ".$stmt->errorCode()." | Affected row count: ".$stmt->rowCount()` in the loop, after `$stmt->execute()` to see if that has any information to show? As an aside, please also verify that the capitalisation of letters in table and column names is correct.

Comment: Still no error producing? This is weird. I also tried wrapping it in a $db->beginTransaction(); and $db->commit(); inside the try in case I wasn't committing. I confirmed capsCase & that db type is InnoDB. Everything LOOKS like it should work.

Comment: Ideally `$stmt->rowCount()` should be `1` (for each successful execution) if there is no error / exception. If it's `0`, then maybe the `id` in question needs a re-check.

Comment: I think I'm finally starting to get somewhere.... I got it to echo the result from above (Error code: 00000 | Affected row count: 0) & to produce an error: Notice: Undefined index: $id in /xxxx/update.php on line 24. (Line 24 if where i set $id = $update_rec['$id'];) I get one of these errors for each of my variables. I tried wrapping these statements in (if(isset)) statement & echo ($update_rec['id']) for all variables & they are all there. Still not sure where the disconnect is but at least I'm getting some feedback now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133917/discussion-between-dhruv-saxena-and-heat222).

Comment: For anyone using this in the future, there is a small typo in the foreach loop, bind params should be like $stmt->bindParam(":user", $updates['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   (Not $updates['$user']) but this solution worked great for me!!